# Airflow: Overriding user_defined_macros in manual runs

Tags: python, testing, google-cloud-platform, airflow, overriding

I have a DAG that runs on a schedule. It uses variables defined in user_defined_macros, while executing query files using BigQueryInsertJobOperator. I want to manually trigger this DAG using another, along with some values to override user_defined_macros parameter.

The called DAG looks something similar to:

```
from airflow.models import DAG, Variable
# other imports

TESTING = Variable.get('TEST_MODE', default_var = False)

if TESTING:
    UDF = { "DS_DEST": "testing" }
else:
    UDF = { "DS_DEST": "data_models" }

with DAG(
    "example_dag",
    schedule_interval = "0 9 * * *",
    start_date = datetime(2023, 1, 1),
    catchup = False,
    user_defined_macros = UDF
) as dag:

    task1 = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
                                        "query": {
                                                    task_id = "dim_campaigns",
                                                    configuration = {
                                                                        "query": "{% include '/queries/data_models/dim_campaigns.sql' %}",
                                                                        "useLegacySql": False,
                                                                    },
                                        },
                                        dag = dag
                                    )
    
    task1
```

...and I am calling it in another DAG similar to the following

```
from airflow.api.client.local_client import Client
client = Client(None, None)

    @task
    def run_dag(dag_id, dag_run_id):
        client.trigger_dag(
            dag_id=dag_id,
            run_id=dag_run_id,
            conf={ "TEST_MODE": True },
            execution_date=datetime.now(pytz.timezone("UTC"))
        )
```

After being called, I look to see in the dag run details that TEST_MODE = True has been sent to the DAG being called, but due to some reason, the TESTING variable does not get the value and the test mode never triggers.

Does anyone know how to fix this or how to override the user_defined_macros when called manually?